# Grid's JQuery code stops working after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I have seen issues similar to this on stackoverflow. However, I have not seen anything re Grids in particular. I am new to jquery so please bear with me.

I have a Html.Grid inside a partial view which receives data and displays them in rows, nothing fancy. When a row is selected, it displays a div on the screen that allows the user to vote on the selected item (row).

So far so good. Things work as expected.

Now, I also have some search capability on the page. When the user clicks the search button, the grid gets refreshed with new data from an action method. The problem then happens at this point because somehow the new rows of the grid lose their association with the actions assigned to them in jquery. I have even tried calling the method again (called prepGrid below) to no use. I am stuck, so any help would be much appreciated. Here below is parts of the code that I have:

```
<script>
    function prepGrid() {
        pageGrids.FeedbackGrid.onRowSelect(function (e) {
            document.getElementById("VoteDiv").style.width = "100%";

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/GetFeatureRequestVotePartial",
                data: { "requestId": e.row.Id },
                success: function (rdata) {
                    $('#VoteDiv').html(rdata);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve the requested feature!.');
                }
            });
        });
    }

    var onSearchClicked = function(){
        var requestId = $('#RequestIdSearch').val();
        var requesterName = $('#RequesterNameSearch').val();
        var title = $('#TitleSearch').val();
        var description = $('#DescriptionSearch').val();

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/GetFeatureRequests",
            data: { "requestId": requestId, "requesterName": requesterName, "title": title, "description": description },
            success: function (rdata) {
                $('#GridDiv').html(rdata);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve request features!.');
            }
        });
    }

    var onVoteClick = function (requestId) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/VoteForRequest",
            data: { "requestId": requestId },
            success: function (rdata) {
                $('#VoteDiv').html(rdata);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve the requested feature!.');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is what I have in _RequestFeatureGridPartial:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Named("FeedbackGrid").Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Add(c => c.Id).Titled("Request Number").SetWidth("10%");
       columns.Add(c => c.NumOfVotes).Titled("Votes").SetWidth("5%").Sortable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.AspNetUser.FullName).Titled("Requester").Filterable(true).SetWidth("15%");
       columns.Add(c => c.RequestedDate).Titled("Date Requested").SetWidth("15%");
       columns.Add(c => c.Title).Titled("Title").SetWidth("20%");
       columns.Add(c => c.Description).Titled("Description")
       .RenderValueAs(c => c.Description.Substring(0, (c.Description.Length > 50) ? 50 : c.Description.Length)
        + ((c.Description.Length > 50) ? "..." : "")).SetWidth("35%");
   }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
</div>
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but does MVC create a JS object called pageGrids of which FeedbackGrid is a property which has an event binding method called onRowSelect? If so, could it be the rows which are linked to this pageGrids.FeedbackGrid object get "lost" once you replace them with the results from your ajax call in onSearchClicked?

Comment: I think two views are created that are called "_Grid.cshtml" and "_GridPager.cshtml". What you're saying would make perfect sense. I just dont know how to re-associate the jquery code to the newly rendered rows.